# Set property as nullable C#

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I have seen two approaches to setting a property as nullable. What is the difference between the two approaches? which one is clean?

```
public string? a { get; set; };
public string b { get; set; } = default!;
```

Edit 1: Updated code to correct syntax and changed int -> string

Comment: `int a?` is not valid C# code.

Comment: I don't think there is a need for `default!` for `public int b { get; set; }` as it is int and *not nullable* type. null forgiving operator is used for reference type. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Comment: (After your edits) The first is correct. Making it nullable is the simple case - what to do if it's non-nullable is more interesting (and not what you're asking of course.)

Answer (score 4):

You wrote `int a?`instead of `int? a`.

The 2 behave very differently here. An `int` is not nullable, its default value is 0. Therefore you can just use defuslt without the `!` . The `!`  just makes the compiler ignore null check rules.
The other creates a real null value.

Lets say we instead had:
`string? a = null`
Or
`string a = default!`
Which behave almost the same, but their type differs.

In that case the `?` nullable reference type is more clean as you dont get rid of the null safety guarantees.

Comment: The sample provided by DDank won't make the variable nullable since it is not implemented correctly `int a?` isn't correct it should be `int? a`

Comment: I misread that. Yes their code doesnt compile.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is correct so to say.
You can understand this clearly using snippet as below.

```
void Main()
{
    var pro = new Pro{
        a = 1,
        //b = 1
    };
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(int));
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?));
}
public class Pro {
    public int? a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; } = default!;  
}
```